# How to disable data cards when my toggle button is "No"?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I'm trying to get all my datacards to be disabled when my toggle button is set to "No". Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't see the images but I can try to answer.

If you want your entire form to be disabled you could set with `ViewForm(Form_Name)` and `EditForm(Form_Name)` when you come back.

If you want specific datacards to be disabled based on a toggle button you should first unlock the datacard, then in `DisplayMode` property you can use `If(toggleName.Value;DisplayMode.Edit;DisplayMode.Disabled)`